# How to fix file icons for icon file (.ico) in Windows explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

After setting a program like Paint 3D as a default program to open .ico files, the Windows explorer doesn't show the icon itself next to the file name anymore. Instead it only displays the icon of the chosen default program. How do you restore it to show the icon itself instead of the icon of the default program?

Comment: I think what you see is entirely normal for all recent versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `Paint` as default program (.ico file > Context menu > `Open with` > tick `always open with`) restores the functionality to show the icon itself next to the file name.

Answer (score 0):

To restore it to show the icon itself instead of the icon of the default program, set Paint as the default program to open with:

.ico file > Context menu > Open with > tick always open with

Also set the file to be available offline if using a file synching service such as Dropbox.

Comment: How is this different to the previous answer ?